# C# - Delete the slash at the end of URI

Tags: c#

I would like to remove the slash at the end of the URI, while keeping the query parameter.

**For example:**

I get an object of **type URI** as input with the value:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/

I would like to remove the last "/" to get:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

---

In some cases I may have parameters:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/?test=test1

I would like to get:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?test=test1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove it where? From your server? From a string?

Comment: From Uri object

Answer (score 3):

```cs
string url1 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/";
string url2 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/?test=test1";

//remove slash at end
Console.WriteLine(url1.TrimEnd('/'));

//remove slash preceding query parameters
int last = url2.LastIndexOf('?');
url2 = url2.Remove(last - 1, 1);
Console.WriteLine(url2);
```

There probably is a way to search and replace the last slash using Regex as well, since there is [`Regex.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Second method is not a good solution. For example, output of "https://stackoverflow.com/users/10189024/cemahseri" would be "https://stackoverflow.com/users/10189024cemahseri", which makes the URL not avaliable anymore.

Comment: @cemahseri thanks for the catch, updated accordingly. Tbh I have never seen URL's where the slash cuts the parameters like `/?` so I had assumed the question was a general remove last occurrence of a slash

Comment: Upvoted! Yup, same. Never seen usage like that. But the OP asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check if the URL has any query parameters by checking latest index of `?` character. If there is `?`, take before that, remove last character *(which is `/` that you don't want)* and combine it again. If it doesn't have any query parameters, just remove the last character! You can create an extension method like this;

```cs
public static string RemoveSlash(this string url)
{
    var queryIndex = url.LastIndexOf('?');
    if (queryIndex >= 0)
    {
        var urlWithoutQueryParameters = url[..queryIndex];
        if (urlWithoutQueryParameters.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            urlWithoutQueryParameters = urlWithoutQueryParameters[..^1];
        }
        var queryParemeters = url[queryIndex..];

        return urlWithoutQueryParameters + queryParemeters;
    }
    else if (url.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        return url[..^1];
    }
    
    return url;
}
```

Then you can use it like this;

```cs
var url1 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
var url2 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/";
Console.WriteLine(url1.RemoveSlash()); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
Console.WriteLine(url2.RemoveSlash()); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

var url3 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/?test=test1";
var url4 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?test=test1";
Console.WriteLine(url3.RemoveSlash()); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?test=test1
Console.WriteLine(url4.RemoveSlash()); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?test=test1
```

Comment: That url2 will not be changed: it doesn't end in a `/` but a `1`

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Updating the code right away.